# ¿Cómo limitar resultados de un JOIN y no del resultado?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Encontré este ejemplo expuesto por A.Cedano. Todo funciona de maravilla excepto que deseo limitar las impresiones por categorías. Es decir, imprimir solo 3 noticias por categoría.

El `LIMIT 3` que he agregado lo único que hace es limitar las categorías existentes y no los enlaces y texto de la noticia. Es decir, si tengo 10 categorías lo que hace es mostrarme solo 3 categorías, pero eso no es lo que busco sino limitar el resultado de datos de impresión, es decir, poder mostrar solo 3 datos por categoría.

¿Qué cambios se debe emplear en el siguiente código?:

```
<?php
    $strSQL="SELECT
            c.title_category,
            GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(n.mini_title,''),'≠',COALESCE(n.url,'') SEPARATOR '|') data
            FROM category c
            INNER JOIN news n ON c.id_category=n.id_category
            WHERE  language=? AND c.active=? AND n.active
            GROUP BY c.id_category
            LIMIT 3";
    if($stmtcategory = $con->prepare($strSQL)){
        $stmtcategory->bind_param("si",$language,$active);
        $stmtcategory->execute();
        $stmtcategory->store_result();
        $strHTML='<div class="date-text">';

        if ($stmtcategory->num_rows>0) {
            $stmtcategory->bind_result($title_category, $data);
            $arrResult=array();
            while ($stmtcategory->fetch()) {
                $arrResult[]=array("title_category"=>$title_category, "data"=>$data);
            }

            foreach ($arrResult as $row){
                $strHTML.="<h4>".$row["title_category"]."</h4>";
                $strHTML.="<ul>";
                $arrTitleNews=explode("|",$row["data"]);

                if(count(array_filter($arrTitleNews)) == 0){
                    $strHTML.="<li><span>No existe noticias nuevas</span></li>";
                } else {
                    foreach ($arrTitleNews as $theData){
                        $arrTitleParts=explode("≠",$theData);
                        $partOne=($arrTitleParts[0]) ? $arrTitleParts[0] : "No data"; //
                        $theTitle=($arrTitleParts[1]) ? '<li><a href="'.$Get_Domain.''.$arrTitleParts[1].'">'.$partOne.'</a></li>' : "";
                        $strHTML.=$theTitle;
                    }
                }

                $strHTML.="</ul>";
            }
        } else {
            $strHTML.="<ul>";
            $strHTML.="<span>No existen noticias nuevas</span>";
            $strHTML.="</ul>";
        }

        $strHTML.="</div>";
        $stmtcategory->close();
    } else {
        $strHTML="Ocurrió un error en la consulta";
    }

    echo $strHTML;
?>
```

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano podría indicarme que pasos se deben agregar al código.

Comment: Que base de datos usas?

Comment: @BetaM MYSQL amigo

Comment: ¿Realmente necesitas hacer uso de `GROUP_CONCAT()`? Si algún título contuviera el carácter `|` no podrías diferenciarlo del separador de `GROUP_CONCAT`. El carácter `≠` es más infrecuente, pero también podrías evitar tener que hacer este tipo de "trucos". ¿Te sugiero una forma mejor de hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente, si usas el `LIMIT 3` al final de la query, se te limitarán el número de categorías.

Para reducir las noticias por categoría, el `LIMIT 3` debe ir en el `GROUP_CONCAT` tal que así:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(
  COALESCE(n.mini_title,''),'≠',
  COALESCE(n.url,''
  SEPARATOR '|'
  LIMIT 3
)
```

Atendiendo al comentario de @OscarGarcia, si tu servidor MySQL no soporta el `LIMIT` en `GROUP_CONCAT`, puedes probar sustituyendo la línea:

```
foreach ($arrTitleNews as $theData){
```

Por:

```
foreach ($arrTitleNews as $i=>$theData) if($i<3){
```

Que básicamente resuelve el problema desde PHP, asignando un número a cada noticia y quedándose con las 3 primeras.

Comment: Por desgracia [tu solución solo es compatible con MariaDB versión 10.3.3 o superior](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/group_concat/#limit). En MySQL (al menos hasta la versión 8.0) no existe la posibilidad de usar [`GROUP_CONCAT()` con `LIMIT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Comment: Gracias @OscarGarcia, modifico la respuesta aportando una solución alternativa desde PHP

Answer (score 1):

Para dar solución a tu problema podrías hacer uso de un `LIMIT` dentro de `GROUP_CONCAT()` como te sufiere [@David JP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/119615/david-jp), pero solo te funcionaría si usas una [versión de MariaDB 10.3.3 o superior](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/group_concat/#limit).

Para que funcione en cualquier versión de MySQL deberías usar este pequeño truco con variables de usuario que te propongo:

```
SELECT
  title_category,
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    COALESCE(mini_title,''),
    CONVERT('≠' USING utf8),
    COALESCE(url,'')
    SEPARATOR '|'
  ) data
FROM (
  SELECT
    IF(@IDC = c.id_category, @NUM := @NUM + 1, @NUM := 1) num,
    @IDC := c.id_category id_category,
    c.title_category,
    n.id_news,
    n.mini_title,
    n.url
  FROM category c
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @IDC := 0, @NUM := 0) iniciar
  INNER JOIN news n
    ON c.id_category = n.id_category
  WHERE
    language = 'es'
    AND c.active = 'S'
    AND n.active
  ) subconsulta
WHERE num <= 3
GROUP BY title_category;
```

¿Qué hace?

Para empezar inicializo las variables de usuario a `0` con `CROSS JOIN (SELECT @IDC := 0, @NUM := 0) iniciar` (para evitar un `SET @IDC := 0, @NUM := 0` previo). En caso contrario el valor inicial sería `null`, provocando comportamientos indeseados.

Para continuar, por cada fila realizo la siguiente comprobación:

- Si el valor de `@IDC` no coincide con `id_category` (hemos empezado una categoría nueva) inicio `@NUM` a `1`.
- Si el valor coincide entonces incremento el valor de `@NUM`.

Tras eso actualizo el valor de `@IDC` al valor de `id_category`.

Esto tiene como efecto un recuento de los elementos dentro de cada categoría, por lo que al final de la consulta puedo filtrar todos los registros que lleven un contador igual o inferior a `3`.

Puedes ver el funcionamiento en línea en la siguiente dirección:

- https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wYin7BRpMnTLKST1vfv7oj/4

---

Aunque te sugeriría cambiar tu código SQL y PHP para que funcione lo siguiente:

```
SELECT
  id_category,
  title_category,
  id_news,
  mini_title,
  url
FROM (
  SELECT
    IF(@IDC = c.id_category, @NUM := @NUM + 1, @NUM := 1) num,
    @IDC := c.id_category id_category,
    c.title_category,
    n.id_news,
    n.mini_title,
    n.url
  FROM category c
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @IDC := 0, @NUM := 0) iniciar
  INNER JOIN news n
    ON c.id_category = n.id_category
  WHERE
    language = 'es'
    AND c.active = 'S'
    AND n.active
  ) subconsulta
WHERE num <= 3
```

Puedes ver el funcionamiento en línea en la siguiente dirección:

- https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wYin7BRpMnTLKST1vfv7oj/1

Este código SQL requerirá cambios en tu código PHP para obtener los datos, ya que cada registro no es una categoría.

---

Para terminar, tengo que avisarte que no deberías usar `GROUP_CONCAT()` para obtener datos agregados obtenidos de otras tablas. Podrías tener problemas si contienen los caracteres que usas como delimitador.

En su lugar deberías usar, por ejemplo, [`JSON_ARRAYAGG()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg). Te permite dar formato JSON a los datos agregados de manera que no es posible una mala interpretación.

Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT
  c.title_category,
  JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('title', n.mini_title, 'url', n.url)) data
FROM category c
INNER JOIN news n
  ON c.id_category=n.id_category
WHERE
  language = 'es'
  AND c.active = 'S'
  AND n.active
GROUP BY c.id_category, c.title_category
```

Ver ejemplo en línea:

- https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wYin7BRpMnTLKST1vfv7oj/3